# Rails 3.0 Ruby-Mysql Gem on Windows - works on Console not on the Server

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3

I've installed Rails 3.0 with an existing version of MySQL 5.3.31 on a Windows XP machine running Ruby 1.8.7, but I am having difficulty connecting to the Mysql database.

The ruby-mysql gem was installed by way of Gemfile and loaded with "bundle install"  and has been verified as version 2.9.4.

When I run the application at the console and run a command such as User.all, it runs perfectly, but when I load up the application server side I receive the error

"Mysql::ProtocolError: invalid packet:"

So question is: why is the database accessible at the console, but not when running the server.

I have also tried the following gems one at time in the Gemfile.
1) gem 'mysql' - which failed to connect either console or server side
2) gem 'mysql2' - which failed to connect either console or server side
3) gem 'mysql-ruby' - which got nowhere

Further note"  I am using mongrel (1.1.5 x86-mingw32) which appears to load cleanly

Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Doug

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been solved. Managed to get the Mysql2 gem to work.